# Get object from field list of xml

Tags: java, xml, jackson, xml-parsing, nested-lists

Please suggest the best solution.
There is the following xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CATALOG>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Greatest Hits</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Dolly Parton</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>RCA</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1982</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Still got the blues</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Gary Moore</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Virgin records</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>10.20</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1990</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Eros</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Eros Ramazzotti</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>BMG</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1997</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>One night only</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Bee Gees</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1998</YEAR>
    </CD>
</CATALOG>
```

also have 5 classes: Catalog, Cd, Album, Artist, Country, Registry

How can i get object of Registry with filled fields:

```
public class Registry {

    private List<Country> countries = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class Country {
    private String name; // <COUNTRY>...</COUNTRY>
    private List<Artist> artists = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class Artist {
    private String name; // <ARTIST>...</ARTIST>
    private List<Album> albums = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class Album {
    private String name; // <TITLE>...</TITLE>
    private int year; // <YEAR>...</YEAR>
}
```

And

- public class Catalog {
- ```
  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "CD")
  ```
- ```
  @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
  ```
- private List cds;
- 
- public List getCds() {
- return cds;
- ```
  }
  ```
- }
- 
- public class Cd {
- ```
  @JsonProperty("TITLE") // Album name
  ```
- private String title;
- 
- ```
  @JsonProperty("ARTIST") // Artist name
  ```
- private String artist;
- 
- ```
  @JsonProperty("COUNTRY") // Country name
  ```
- private String country;
- 
- ```
  @JsonProperty("COMPANY")
  ```
- private String company;
- 
- ```
  @JsonProperty("PRICE")
  ```
- private double price;
- 
- ```
  @JsonProperty("YEAR")  // Album year
  ```
- private int year;
- }

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use Powershell.  Below will input xml in to table.  Than you can use Group-Object or Sort-Object.  The NotePropertyName is a hash.

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

$Filename = "c:\temp\test.xml"

$albums = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()  

$xDoc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($Filename)
foreach($cd in $xDoc.Descendants("CD"))
{
   $newAlbum = New-Object -TypeName psobject
   
   $title = $cd.Element("TITLE").Value
   $newAlbum | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Title -NotePropertyValue $title

   $artist = $cd.Element("ARTIST").Value
   $newAlbum | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Artist -NotePropertyValue $artist   
   
   $country = $cd.Element("COUNTRY").Value
   $newAlbum | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Country -NotePropertyValue $country   
   
   $company = $cd.Element("COMPANY").Value
   $newAlbum | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Company -NotePropertyValue $company   
   
   $price = [decimal]$cd.Element("PRICE").Value
   $newAlbum | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Price -NotePropertyValue $price
     
   $year = [int]$cd.Element("YEAR").Value
   $newAlbum | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Year -NotePropertyValue $year


   $albums.Add($newAlbum) | Out-Null
}
Write-Host "All Albums"
$albums | Format-Table
```